# Как активировать функцию php при нажатии тега <a>?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня есть вот такой код

```
<a href="images/xxx.jpg" download onclick="isEmail()">Click Me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function isEmail() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                 document.write("data");
                }
            });

}); }
</script>
```

Но проблема в том что при нажатий на тег 
Исчезает все кроме самого script.php

А мне нужно что бы при нажатий на тег (а) php код вывелся после javascript

Например так

```
<script>
  document.write('<?php echo "<h3>tre</h3>";?>');
</script>
<h3>tre</h3>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickme").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'script.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $("body").append(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $("body").append($("<h3></h3>").text("ERROR: " + status));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое